# Retrieving text from JTextField

Tags: java, swing

The concept of my code is that, it will initially retrieve distinct names from a column 'tname' of my access database table 'try'. It will add those items in a combobox. Once we select an item in the combo box, the data of the row containing tname as the selected item is retrieved and showed in textfields. Then I will make some changes to the text field content. After that, if I click 'Save' button, then all the data of the row containing tname as the selected combobox item must be updated with the new content in the textfields.

Everything goes fine, except the last one. When I click 'save' it considers only the previous text(the one intially retrieved from the database when we select combobox) and not the changes made to it. Kindly help me to diagnose the problem.

Thanks in advance.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import java.util.Date;
import java.sql.*;
import java.text.*;

public class gut implements ActionListener
{
JComboBox ctn;
JTextField cm,exd,stk,cst,sup,snum,r;
String stn,scm,sexd,sst,scst,ssup,ssnum,sr,icm,iexd,istk,icst,isup,isnum,ir;
JLabel lt,lc,le,ls,lcs,lsp,lspn,lr;
JButton s;
JFrame gp=new JFrame();

public gut()
{
gp.setSize(500,500);
gp.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

gp.setLayout(null);

lt=new JLabel("Tablet Name",JLabel.RIGHT);
lc=new JLabel("Composition",JLabel.RIGHT);
le=new JLabel("Expiry Date (dd/mm/yyyy)",JLabel.RIGHT);
ls=new JLabel("Stock",JLabel.RIGHT);
lcs=new JLabel("Cost",JLabel.RIGHT);
lsp=new JLabel("Supplier",JLabel.RIGHT);
lspn=new JLabel("Supplier Number",JLabel.RIGHT);
lr=new JLabel("Rack",JLabel.RIGHT);

lt.setBounds(100,120,120,20);
lc.setBounds(100,140,120,20);
le.setBounds(60,160,160,20);
ls.setBounds(100,180,120,20);
lcs.setBounds(100,200,120,20);
lsp.setBounds(100,220,120,20);
lspn.setBounds(100,240,120,20);
lr.setBounds(100,260,120,20);

ctn=new JComboBox();
cm=new JTextField();
exd=new JTextField();
stk=new JTextField();
cst=new JTextField();
sup=new JTextField();
snum=new JTextField();
r=new JTextField();


ctn.setBounds(240,120,120,20);
cm.setBounds(240,140,120,20);
exd.setBounds(240,160,120,20);
stk.setBounds(240,180,120,20);
cst.setBounds(240,200,120,20);
sup.setBounds(240,220,120,20);
snum.setBounds(240,240,120,20);
r.setBounds(240,260,120,20);

try
{
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:vasantham","","");
Statement st=conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select DISTINCT tname from try");

while(rs.next())
{
 ctn.addItem(rs.getString("tname"));
}

conn.close();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
}

gp.add(lt);gp.add(ctn);
gp.add(lc);gp.add(cm);
gp.add(le);gp.add(exd);
gp.add(ls);gp.add(stk);
gp.add(lcs);gp.add(cst);
gp.add(lsp);gp.add(sup);
gp.add(lspn);gp.add(snum);
gp.add(lr);gp.add(r);

ctn.addActionListener(this);
s=new JButton("Save");
s.setBounds(200,300,100,20);
gp.add(s);
s.addActionListener(this);




gp.setVisible(true);
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
{
String act=evt.getActionCommand();

String scb=(String)ctn.getSelectedItem();
try
{
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:vasantham","","");
Statement st=conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from try where tname='"+scb+"'");
SimpleDateFormat formatter=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

while(rs.next())
{
icm=rs.getString("composition");
iexd=formatter.format(rs.getDate("exdate"));
istk=Integer.toString(rs.getInt("stock"));
icst=rs.getString("cost");
isup=rs.getString("sup");
isnum=rs.getString("supnum");
ir=rs.getString("rack");
}

cm.setText(icm);
exd.setText(iexd);
stk.setText(istk);
cst.setText(icst);
sup.setText(isup);
snum.setText(isnum);
r.setText(ir);


conn.close();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
System.out.println(e);
}


if(act.equals("Save"))
{
scm=cm.getText();
sexd=exd.getText();
sst=stk.getText();
scst=cst.getText();
ssup=sup.getText();
ssnum=snum.getText();
sr=r.getText();
System.out.println(scm+","+sexd+","+sst+","+scst+","+ssup+","+ssnum+","+sr);
try
{

Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:vasantham","","");
PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE try set composition=?,exdate=?,stock=?,cost=?,sup=?,supnum=?,rack=? where 

tname=?");

ps.setString(1,scm);
ps.setString(2,sexd);
ps.setString(3,sst);
ps.setString(4,scst);
ps.setString(5,ssup);
ps.setString(6,ssnum);
ps.setString(7,sr);
ps.setString(8,scb);

ps.executeUpdate();

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your entry has been stored successfully!!!");

}
catch(Exception e)
{
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error!Try again!");
System.out.println(e);

}
}
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
new gut();
}

}
```

Comment: Slightly off-topic: going by java naming convention, the class name should start with an upper letter

Comment: @Sujay But, that doesn't matter Sujay. Is there any method to solve my problem?

Comment: No.It's not empty. I printed it out and tried. Only thing, even after i change the content and press Save,the content changes back to previous entry

Comment: I've never set JLabels and JTextFields directly to a JFrame.  You ought to have a JPanel to hold the JLabels and JTextFields.  You also ought to be using a Swing layout manager, like GridBagLayout, rather than using direct positioning.  Swing expects components to be laid out in a specific way, and your layout could be why your JTextField getText method calls aren't returning what you think they should.

Comment: You might like to read through http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html to gain a better understanding of the action listeners

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On top of what everybody else has already said, if you REALLY want to use a single action listener, you are going to need to work out which action has actually occurred.

You could check the source of the ActionEvent (`evt.getSource()`) or, more appropriately, you could assign a action command to each component using the action listener.

Check out [JComboBox.setActionCommand(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#setActionCommand%28java.lang.String%29) and [JButton.setActionCommand(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setActionCommand%28java.lang.String%29)

After that, it's a simple case of checking the [ActionEvent.getActionCommand()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionEvent.html#getActionCommand%28%29) property to determine the correct action to take.

Comment: It worked! I added a setActionCommand to the combobox and checked over to it in actionPerformed and added my coding there. Thank you so much,Sir.

Comment: At least I've helped someone today ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your actionPerformed() function retrieves the information from the database every time. If you press the Save button it will first retrieve the information and then save the information if the action command is "Save". This is why you always get the information that's currently in the database from getText() when pressing the Save button.

Make a different function / actionListener to execute when the Save button is pressed or take the part of the code that updates the text fields else where.

Try something like this instead:

```
JButton saveButton = new JButton( new AbstractAction("save") {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
            // Save the info here or just call a function that will.
        }
    });
```

Comment: How to modify my code by adding separate action listener to Save button,Sir?

Comment: I did as you told, Sir. But, still no change, Sir.

Comment: Can you update the code in your original post or provide a link to the updated code please?

Comment: I added a setActionCommand to the comboBox and checked it in actionPerformed.It worked, Sir. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that every time you hit the "Save" button you are retrieving the information from the database over again, so, you overwrite the TextFields and then you read from the TexFields content. Try to take out this part:

```
 try {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection

            ("jdbc:odbc:vasantham", "", "");
            Statement st = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from try where tname='"
                    + scb + "'");
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

            while (rs.next()) {
                icm = rs.getString("composition");
                iexd = formatter.format(rs.getDate("exdate"));
                istk = Integer.toString(rs.getInt("stock"));
                icst = rs.getString("cost");
                isup = rs.getString("sup");
                isnum = rs.getString("supnum");
                ir = rs.getString("rack");
            }

            cm.setText(icm);
            exd.setText(iexd);
            stk.setText(istk);
            cst.setText(icst);
            sup.setText(isup);
            snum.setText(isnum);
            r.setText(ir);

            conn.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
```

from the action performed method.

Comment: But I need the content to be displayed when an item is selected in combobox. If I remove this, won't I miss that requirement?

Comment: You can ask the event where it comes from, and only process that part if it does not come from the Save button.

Comment: How can I differentiate it Sir? I'm a beginner! Kindly guide me.

Comment: You are already doing that when you ask "if(act.equals("Save"))" you can try to put that piece of code in the else clause of that if, that might help you with this issue, but it is by no means good practice.

Answer (score 1):

Every time your action event is fired, you read data from DB and write it into the textfields.
You can change that text and it will be displayed correctly in your textfields. But when you click save, all your changes are overwritten with the DB values again.

So you have to separate the functionalities "read from DB" and "write changes".

edit:
oops, too slow..

Comment: Do you mean I need an additional button to retrieve and Save button to write,Sir?